# drush: no path to user login after archive-restore

Tags: drupal-7, backup, drush

I'm having the following issue:

I backed up my Drupal7 project on my localhost via

```
$ drush archive-dump --destination=/var/backup/example.com.tar.gz
```

using drush 6.1.0 on my Ubuntu 12.04. (apache2/php5.3.10/mysql 5.5.34).

I then tried to restore it to my Mac (OSX Lion) via

```
$ sudo drush archive-restore /var/backup/example.com.tar.gz \
--destination=/var/www/example.com \
--db-su=root --db-su-pw=password --overwrite
```

Everything worked fine (Website is available, database and correct useres are created, except the fact that I cannot login anymore to the transferred Drupal project. The path to /drupal/user is simply not there. What went wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: hi just a wild guess. try disabling clean url

Answer (score 0):

Solved - see comment from Deepak Srinivasan.